# Insert Image from another table based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to `SQL` (have only been in my position for a few weeks with no prior experience) so please excuse me if this is an obvious question!

**Context**

I've got two tables - table 1 which contains two images (for this instance we'll call them 'Yes' and 'No' - both saved as `varbinary(max))` and table 2 that contains all my other data.

I've created a new column in table 2 called Image that I want to populate with one of the images based on the value in another column ('Drivable') in table 2. The column 'Drivable' will either contain the values 'Yes', 'No' or NULL.

**Question**

I think I need to use a case statement but not entirely sure how to go about it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance for any reply - if you need any more information then please let me know.

:)

Comment: Check out the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: How do you want to determine (logically, not in code :) ) which column from table 1 should go to the Image column?

Comment: I've just made a change - In table 1 I now have a field called 'ImgGroup' that I've stored as a Bit, and I've also changed the column 'Drivable' in table 2 to a Bit. I need to join on these columns I think

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL Server... I've managed to get this done now thanks - here was my solution :

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem using the below:

```
SELECT
 T.ClaimId
 ,I1.[Photo] as DriveableImage
FROM
 Table1 as T
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 Table2 as I1 
ON
 I1.ImageGroup = C.Drivable
```